# Is the EU settlement status the same as a resident card?

Tags: visas, france, eu

My wife has eu settlement status, I am a French citizen, we both live and work in the UK.

Can she travel to france with me, without requiring a visa? or will she now need a new visa to travel to France.

Answer (score 1):

No, the EU settlement scheme just also you to live, work and study in the UK. It does not entitle you to visit France or any other EU countries visa free.

More details on the scheme are mentioned on the [GOV website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/eu-settlement-scheme-community-leaders-toolkit/eu-settlement-scheme-briefing-information-communicating-the-facts).